# jquery :: on orientationchange does not replace an element

Tags: jquery, mobile

I start learning how I can make my web content more interesting for mobile devices.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        placeContent();         
    });

function placeContent(){
         var h = $(document).height();
         h -= $('#PageWrapper').height();
         h /= parseInt(2);
         $('#PageWrapper').css( "margin-top", h + "px" );
    }

$( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
        placeContent();
    });
```

the method to replace the content does not work. 
It just should concentrate the content to the center of the screen.

Regards
NetBu||

Answer (score 0):

changed my code to:

```
<script>

    function placeContent(){
         var h = $(document).height();
         h -= $('#PageWrapper').height();
         h /= parseInt(2);
         $('#PageWrapper').css( "margin-top", h + "px" );
         write("lreplaced the content....");
    }

    function setBodiesClass(){
        if( getDeviceType() == "mobile" ){              
            if($(document).height() > $(document).width()){
                $("body").attr( "class", "portrait" )
                write("load portrait style");
            } else {
                $("body").attr( "class", "landscape" )
                write("load landscape style");
            }               
        } else {                
            $("body").attr( "class", "browser" )
            write("load browsers style");
        }
    }

    function getDeviceType(){
        sReturn = null;
        if( sDeviceType == null ){
            if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
                sReturn = "mobile";
            } else {
                sReturn = "browser";
            }
        }
        return sReturn;
    }

    function write(sMessage){
        $("#Messages").append("<p>" + sMessage + "</p>");
    }

    function onLoadOrOrientationChanged(){
        setBodiesClass();
        placeContent();
    }

    $(document).ready( function(  ){
        write("page was ready");
        onLoadOrOrientationChanged();
    });

    /*
    $( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
        write("page orientation changed");
        onLoadOrOrientationChanged();
    });
    */

    var orientationEvent = "onorientationchange" in window ? "orientationchange" : "resize";
    $(window).on(orientationEvent, function() {
        onLoadOrOrientationChanged();
    });

</script>
```

Misterious: 
moving from landscape to protrait it says: 
-> load landscape style
and moving back to landscape it says 
-> load portrait style

But the placeContent function did not replace the content... 
But an write method after replacing the content gets fired...